# Java regexp to remove Freemarker FTL tags

Tags: java, regex, freemarker

I'm trying to create a regexp to ignore Freemarker FTL tags in a String.
I've a template with text and [FTL tags](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_overallstructure.html) for example `"Hi, [#if gender="Male"]Mr[#elseif]Mrs[/#if] ${name} I've a special offer for you."`

I want replace only FTL tags, so only tags that have `[#something]` pattern: I'm usings square bracket syntax.

Ideally I should call "`myString".replaceAll("regex","");`

but I'm not able to find the right regexp to use.

The final String result I want obtain after the replacement is `"Hi, Mr Mrs ${name} I've a special offer for you."`

Comment: What is the expected output after the replaceAll for the sample str? Do you want to keep the "Mr/Mrs" or just show the ${name}, like `Hi, ${name}`?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the final result I expect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern should do what you expect:

`\[/?#(.+?)\]`

Test case:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String PATTERN = "\\[/?#(.+?)\\]";
    private static final String TEXT = "Hi, [#if gender=\"Male\"]Mr[#elseif]Mrs[/#if] ${name} I've a special offer for you.";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String out = TEXT.replaceAll(PATTERN, "");
        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

Output:
`Hi, MrMrs ${name} I've a special offer for you.`

Comment: that pattern will take anything within [] not, just [#]. Also, .+? could just be .*

Comment: You are right regarding the # part, and will edit the answer. On the other hand replacing +? for * won't produce the same result. i.e. for the given String, it will return `Hi,  ${name} I've a special offer for you.`

Comment: you're right, adding the ? adds eager look ahead to the expression

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String template = "<html>[BR]\n"
                      + "<head>[BR]\n"
                      + "  <title>Welcome!</title>[BR]\n"
                      + "</head>[BR]\n"
                      + "<body>[BR]\n"
                      + "  [#-- Greet the user with his/her name --][BR]\n"
                      + "  <h1>Welcome ${user}!</h1>[BR]\n"
                      + "  <p>We have these animals:[BR]\n"
                      + "  <ul>[BR]\n"
                      + "  [#list animals as animal][BR]\n"
                      + "    <li>${animal.name} for ${animal.price} Euros[BR]\n"
                      + "  [/#list][BR]\n"
                      + "  </ul>[BR]\n"
                      + "</body>[BR]\n"
                      + "</html>";

    System.out.println("************ORIGINAL TEMPLATE**************");
    System.out.println(template);
    System.out.println("************REPLACED TEMPLATE**************");
    System.out.println(template.replaceAll("\\[/?#(.*?)\\]", "\u001B[33mREPLACEMENT\u001B[0m"));
}
```